# What is the meaning of the listIterator API description?

Tags: java, api

This API:

```
/// Returns a list iterator of the elements in this list (in proper sequence)
public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index)
```

What is the meaning of *proper sequence*?

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

// Is the sequence returned by i1 and i2 is the same?
ListIterator<Integer> i1 = list.listIterator();
ListIterator<Integer> i2 = list.listIterator();

i1.next();

int result = i1.next(); // Is result 2? Or random?
```

Comment: please check your code it is not clear what list.next() should do

Comment: List list doesn't have next() methode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When iterate in ListIterator object return in order of index proper mean that, and i1, i2 is independent:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);

        // Is the sequence returned by i1 and i2 is the same?
        ListIterator<Integer> i1 = list.listIterator();
        ListIterator<Integer> i2 = list.listIterator();

        while (i1.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(i1.next());
        }
        while (i2.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(i2.next());
        }    
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 3):

> Returns a list iterator of the elements in this list (in proper sequence)

This means the `ListIterator.next()` method will return the list's elements in the order that they appear in the list.  The same applies in the other places in the List javadocs where they use the phrase "the proper sequence".

Answer (score 2):

Yes the result will be 2, proper sequence for array lists means in order of index.